# The recursive systems of equations with the following form, have they ever been considered?

Tags: recurrence-relations, systems-of-equations

Suppose a system of 2 equations defined as:

$$\begin{cases}
x_{n+1}&=f_x(x_n,y_n) \\
y_{n+1}&=f_y(x_n,y_n)
\end{cases}$$

where initial conditions for $x_0$ and $y_0$ are defined, and $x_n,y_n\in\Bbb R$, $f_x,f_y:\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$.

I found that if $f_x(x,y)=\cos(x+y)+\sin(x-y)$ and $f_y(x,y)=\cos(x-y)+\sin(x+y)$. Then the system becomes

$$\begin{cases}
x_{n+1}&=\cos(x_n+y_n)+\sin(x_n-y_n)\\
y_{n+1}&=\cos(x_n-y_n)+\sin(x_n+y_n)
\end{cases}$$

which for any starting values for $x_0$ and $y_0$ it will produce the following points(plotted $x$ horizontally and until $x_{1.000.000}$):

[image]

which creates a rather interesting structure(I think its called an attractor), and I'd love to hear more about these systems, but couldn't find anything. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT:**

If the system is

$$\begin{cases}
x_{n+1}&= \cos(x_n^2+y_n^2) \\
y_{n+1}&= \sin(x_n^2-y_n^2)
\end{cases}$$

The points would be the following:

[image]

Are these coming from some differential equations?

Comment: Maybe using the equation $cos(a+b)=Re(e^{i(a+b)})$ and $sin(a + b) = Im(e^{i(a + b)})$ and combining two levels of the recursion it's possible to find simpler equation for the same system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, such recurrences have been studied extensively and are still subject to resear in the field of [Dynamical Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_system), *discrete time dynamical systems* in particular. In this field the behaviour of repeated applications of a function (in your case $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$) to some inputs is studied.